# How to run a jmeter load test with webdriver samplers on blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, blazemeter

How to run a jmeter load test with webdriver samplers on blazemeter? Is it possible to run this jmx file on blazemeter? also on blazemeter how do I include the files needed to run the scripts such as csv and chrome driver?

Answer (score 0):

You should address this form of questions to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-open-a-support-ticket-).

From what can be seen from BlazeMeter's [How to run a Selenium Performance Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000805797-How-to-run-a-Selenium-Performance-Test) article they definitely support executing Selenium tests via [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) automation framework.

Check out documentation on [Taurus Selenium Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) for comprehensive information. You might also use [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension v4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) to record your Selenium test.